# Efficiently delete row when singe data is in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete specific rows from an excel sheet, if the data contained in a specific cell are different from their *neighbors*

The sheet is already sorted, as a result I can have this comparison.

The issue here is that, although a sheet around 3,000 lines would take less than a minute, when this escalates to 60,000 the function seems to never end.

Is there something wrong in what I am trying?
Is there a more efficient way?

```
Private Function DeleteSingleItemLines() As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    lastRow = lastRow - 2

    For rwIndex = 6 To lastRow
        If Cells(rwIndex, "B").Value <> Cells(rwIndex + 1, "B").Value _
        And Cells(rwIndex, "B").Value <> Cells(rwIndex - 1, "B").Value Then
            Rows(rwIndex & ":" & rwIndex).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            lastRow = lastRow - 1
            rwIndex = rwIndex - 1
        End If
    Next rwIndex

    DeleteSingleItemLines = lastRow
End Function
```

Comment: It might be a bit faster if you start at the bottom and work your way up.  You'd also be able to omit adjusting `rwIndex` and `lastRow` with each deletion.  You should disable screen updating and set calculation to manual.  Finally, if the contents are NOT formulas, it may run much faster if you read the range into a VBA array `arrStuff = Range(Cells(6,1), Cells(lastRow,lastColumn)`, then iterate through the array collecting the retained lines into a collection; write the collection to a new array, and write back the array to the worksheet.

Comment: I definitely think that this will run a *lot* faster if you work from the bottom up.  Why?  Because if you're comparing row #12345 to #(12345-1), then it doesn't matter to the logic whether-or-not you decide to delete that row:  "the next row to be processed" will always be ... #12344.  Also, such a loop is guaranteed to consider every row in the original range, no matter how many deletes it decided to do along the way.  You simply loop `lastRow to 6 step -1`.  (Also:  if you're doing very voluminous edits to a spreadsheet, temporarily disable recalculation.)

Comment: I think the reverse way made some difference, still it is quite slow. I will try to have a look in the array. Thanks a lot for your replies! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, with very small changes in your code you can make it faster by setting the property ScreenUpdating to false (write this code right after declaring variables) as in:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

The code above keeps Excel without rendering changes in the screen and makes processing a lot faster.

Thinking about your problem in another way, you could put a formula inside your worksheet returning TRUE or FALSE for the condition you have and then use a AutoFilter to delete them all at once. It is possible to do that in vba code also.

Best regards,

Abe